# changing an edit text from another activiy after clicking a button

Tags: android-studio

Okay so I'm new at programming, and for a school project I have to make a coffee shop app in android studio.

What I want to know, is how can I after clicking a button, edit a space for text to add text about the item they will buy but place it in another activity.

The thing is I want to make a kind of add to cart thing, and after going to the cart tab, there is an edit text where you see how much the account will be.

Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Alert Dialog with Edit Text and pass the values using Shared Preference.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater=MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
//this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.editxml,null);
alert.setView(layout);
alert.setTitle("Enter Name");
final EditText usernameInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//do your stuff here
     }
   });
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
dialog.dismiss();
      }
  });
alert.show();
```

editxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10"
 android:id="@+id/editText1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so I should put the alert dialog on the class of the activity where the button is and the EditText in the activity of the "cart or checkout" tab where the info appears?

Comment: add the alert dialog on the onclicklistener of the button. and create a separate xml file with a edit text for the alert dialog.